# Simulating keypress in FMX application

Tags: android, delphi, keyboard, firemonkey

Is there a possibility when you enter a `TMemo` the first thing that automatically will be done is the key press of the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key? I've read about the `SendInput()` procedure, but I made a big mess of it, so that's why I am asking this question.

First time for me to make this in an app. The app runs on Android.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this approach?

Comment: @SilverWarior Well, it's a workaround for a bug that I have with the tmemo. When I typed in the tmemo for the first time it is good. but when I leave and want to type again the cursor always jumps to the beginning of the tmemo and replaces the first character. but when I first hit the del key and then start typing it doesn't jump back and replaces the character.

Comment: It would be better if you try to track the bug you are encountering instead of trying to use such unusual workaround. I mean let's say you manage to make this workaround and then the original bug gets fixed. At that time your workaround becomes a bug.

Comment: Based on your description of the bug I'm guessing that setting focus to the TMemo component for the second time might be selecting the first character in memo and then starting to write one of these so called [Compose keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) or [Dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) characters because pressing Delete key does cancel the creation of Compose or Dead key character. Now if I'm right you only need to figure out where these come from.

Comment: And for that knowing of how you are getting or leaving the TMemo focus may come very helpful. Another helpful information might be whether you using default native or custom onscreen keyboard and if you are perhaps using some less common input language.

Comment: @SilverWarior Thank you for this information! It's always better to solve the bug than make a workaround. But I didn't know where to start with this bug. Now you gave me this information I have a better image of where the possible bug will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could checkout kbmFMX Pro which contains a virtual keyboard that will work with existing controls.

It is rather complex in Firemonkey to create a virtual keyboard and simulate key presses and involves getting access to TTextService and other features of Firemonkey.

If on Windows only, you *can* send windows messages to the window for key down and key up, but that is also relatively complex when simulating control/shift/alt keys.